# Difference between てぶくろ and グローブ

Tags: word-choice, words, nuances

According to jisho.org, [グローブ](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%82%B0%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%96) seems to have a "sports" nuance to it, wherease [手袋{てぶくろ}](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%A6%E3%81%B6%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8D) seems to be more general. Is this accurate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exactly. See how different they are. (Sorry for oversized image.)

[image]

We imagine 手袋 as a kind of clothes for everyday life and work, and グローブ as a sports gear. Of course, more accurate transcription of *glove* is [グラブ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%96_%28%E9%87%8E%E7%90%83%29), which is preferred by baseball players.

Some Japanese traditional sports have gloves that are never called グローブ. For example, in 剣道【けんどう】 they use [小手【こて】（籠手）](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%B1%A0%E6%89%8B) (but technically because it's rather like cloth gauntlet).

Comment: Don't forget bike gloves as well; I suppose they're sports-like although used for everyday life.

Comment: @syockit Good point. Gloves for boxing or serious bike/motorcycle riding equally deserve to be グローブ. I wear mittens with fingers during winter riding, and I think they're 手袋.